# Custom related list Lightning component for History table related list - delay in fetching

Tags: lightning-aura-components, field-history, cacheable

I created a Custom related list (Component A) that fetches history table and displays. It has a button to refresh the history list.
In the same page, I have another lightning component (Component B) which calls Custom Apex controller to update the record.  I do the following steps

1. I update the record with Component B.
2. I click refresh button on Component A. But the response does not pick up the latest changes from history table.I have wait for 3-4 seconds before the latest history records are fetched. At the same time, I can see the history table is already updated using SOQL.

This happens only with history tables. Has anyone observed this behaviour ? Is there a way to resolve this issue ?

Another question -  Is "@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)" mandatory for Apex Controller fetch methods called from Lightning Components ? If I remove "Cacheable=true" I get the below error - "Apex methods that are to be cached must be marked as @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)"

```
Apex Controller 

@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static Map<String,Object> getCMEngagementHistories(Id recordId){
        Map<String,Object> response = CM_EngagementService.getCMEngagementHistories(recordId);
        System.debug(response);
        return response;
    }

Apex Service

public static Map<String,Object> getCMEngagementHistories(Id recordId) {
        List<CM_Onboarding__History> onboardingHistories = [
                SELECT
                        CreatedBy.Name,
                        CreatedDate,
                        Field,
                        Id,
                        NewValue,
                        OldValue,
                        ParentId
                FROM CM_Onboarding__History
                where ParentId = :recordId
                order by createdDate desc
                limit 10
        ];
        List<CMHistoryDTO> newhistoryList = new List<CMHistoryDTO>();
        for(CM_Onboarding__History h:onboardingHistories){
            CMHistoryDTO hh = new CMHistoryDTO();
            hh.CreatedBy = h.CreatedBy.Name;
            hh.CreatedDate = h.CreatedDate;
            hh.Field = h.Field;
            hh.NewValue = h.NewValue;
            hh.OldValue = h.OldValue;

            if(hh.Field != null && Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('CM_Onboarding__c').getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(hh.Field) != null){
                hh.Field = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('CM_Onboarding__c').getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(hh.Field).getDescribe().getLabel();

            }
            if (newhistoryList.size() < 5){
                if(h.OldValue == null || (h.OldValue != null && !(String.valueof(h.OldValue).startsWith('00')))){
                    newhistoryList.add(hh);
                }
            }
        }

        Map<String,Object> localResponse = new Map<String,Object>();
        localResponse.put(cmOnboardingHistoriesKey, newhistoryList);
        return localResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the Apex code that is performing the query

Comment: @BryanAnderson Added the code

Comment: The cacheable annotation could be causing a delay between the client side and server side determining whether to query the database again. What happens if you remove the cacheable annotation. Are you doing `setStorable()` in your Aura component?

Comment: If I remove cacheable, I get below error "Apex methods that are to be cached must be marked as @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)".  I did not use setStorable() in the lightning component

Comment: Not all methods need to be marked cachable, but I am wondering if there is a dependency from something in your client side code that is causing this (I.e. `setStorable()`)

Comment: @BryanAnderson I got the issue resolved. Somehow got the clue from https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212552/apex-class-non-static-auraenabled-methods-may-not-have-parameters?rq=1 . When I rename the controller method not to start with "get" and remove Cacheable, then I am getting the response swiftly. If the controller method prefixed as "get" then I need to add "cacheable = true". Otherwise I get error response in lightning component.

Comment: Great excellent to hear! Sorry I was not more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe once an apex method is set as cacheable=true, salesforce at runtime always expects the cacheable as true. If I remove cacheable, at runtime I get the above error in lightning component. When I rename the method and do not add cacheable then it works fine.
I have observed this behaviour couple of times now. So resolution would be simply to rename the method and remove cacheable